# is it possilbe to list all shared drive(TeamDrive) list and the folders inside the drives?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

i want to know if it's possible to list all drives id list and the folder's Id inside of all drives?

for the moment i can only get the list of drives

```
 var request = service.Files.Get(driveFileId);

            request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
            request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
            request.Fields = "*";
            var result = request.Execute();
            return request.Execute();
```

Comment: Something to do with it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272920/c-sharp-google-drive-sdk-how-to-get-a-list-of-google-drive-folders

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question.  Your code will list all of the files and directories.   Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: @Nando that question is from 2012 the library has changed a lot since then i dont think thats going to help at all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible

1. You can list the drives with the method [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list)
2. You can list the folders within those drives with [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) by specifying the [`q` parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) as

```
request.Q = "'XXX' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

whereby XXX should be replaced by the id / variable containing the id of the shared drive.